# Searching SQL via Windows Form

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio

I've googled this for quite some time but I'm just not sure 'how' to pose the question so that google knows what I mean. I have an application that I'm developing in visual studio. Right now it's just a basic windows form with a search text box for a user to enter data and a search button to search the sql database and return the row that matches. The end user is searching for a student based on the entered student number. I have populated the sql db with two dummy students as to have data to test with. When I enter the first student number and click search, it works fine. When I enter the second number, works fine again. When I click search with no data in the box, works fine as well and throws me my custom error message. It's when I enter an invalid number, one that is not in the database, that nothing happens. It still shows the previous record I just successfully retrieved and clears the text box and puts the cursor back in the box and gives it focus (as it should) but doesn't tell me it can't find that specific number in the db. I can't seem to figure out how or where in my code to fix this.

Background: I am self taught in programming languages (youtube segments, harvard's free online 'how to's', google, numerous books read, etc) and grasp the basic fundamentals of the syntax etc but no where near where I want to be. I LOVE developing software as a hobby and love learning how to do it. Any help is extremely appreciated. Just be gentle. :-)

I have removed sensitive information on purpose and replaced them with '?'. Here is my current code:

```
    Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

    If stunumtxtbox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a student number.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        stunumtxtbox.Select()
    Else
        Try
            con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=?\?;Initial Catalog=?;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=?;Password=?"
            con.Open()
        Catch se As SqlException
            MsgBox(se.Message)
        Finally

            Try
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
                ds.Tables.Add(dt)
                da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Student_Info WHERE studentId = '" & stunumtxtbox.Text & "'", con)
                da.Fill(dt)
                For Each DataRow In dt.Rows
                    If stunumtxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("studentId").ToString Then
                        fnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("firstName").ToString
                        mnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("midleInitial").ToString
                        lnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("lastName").ToString
                        addresstxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressStreet").ToString
                        address2txtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressOption").ToString
                        citytxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressCity").ToString
                        statetxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressState").ToString
                        ziptxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressZip").ToString
                        countrytxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressCountry").ToString
                        celltxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("contactcellphone").ToString
                        studentidtxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("studentId").ToString
                    Else
                    End If
                Next
                con.Close()
            Catch se As SqlException
                MsgBox(se.Message)
            Finally
                stunumtxtbox.Clear()
                stunumtxtbox.Select()
                Try
                    StudentNameTextBox.Text = lnametxtbox.Text + "," + " " + fnametxtbox.Text + " " + mnametxtbox.Text
                Catch ex As Exception
                    MsgBox(ex.Message)
                Finally
                    fnamelabel.Visible = True
                    mnamelabel.Visible = True
                    lnamelabel.Visible = True
                    addressstreetlabel.Visible = True
                    address2label.Visible = True
                    addresscitylabel.Visible = True
                    addressstatelabel.Visible = True
                    addressziplabel.Visible = True
                    addresscountrylabel.Visible = True
                    celllabel.Visible = True
                    studentidlabel.Visible = True
                    editbutton.Enabled = True
                    editbutton.Visible = True
                End Try
            End Try
        End Try
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @DonA and @Michael for helping me!! Using your info and a few more google's, I devised the following code and very happy to say that it works. :-)

```
Private Sub SearchButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles SearchButton.Click

    If stunumtxtbox.Text = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please enter a student number.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
        stunumtxtbox.Select()
    Else
        Try
            Using connection As New SqlConnection("Data Source=?;Initial Catalog=?;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=?;Password=?")
                connection.Open()
                Dim dt As New DataTable
                Dim ds As New DataSet
                Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
                ds.Tables.Add(dt)
                da = New SqlDataAdapter("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Student_Info WHERE studentId = '" & stunumtxtbox.Text & "'", connection)
                Dim count = da.Fill(dt)

                If count = 0 Then
                    MsgBox("Student ID not found.", MsgBoxStyle.Critical)
                Else
                    fnamelabel.Visible = True
                    mnamelabel.Visible = True
                    lnamelabel.Visible = True
                    addressstreetlabel.Visible = True
                    address2label.Visible = True
                    addresscitylabel.Visible = True
                    addressstatelabel.Visible = True
                    addressziplabel.Visible = True
                    addresscountrylabel.Visible = True
                    celllabel.Visible = True
                    studentidlabel.Visible = True
                    EditStudentToolStripMenuItem.Enabled = True

                    fnametxtbox.Enabled = False
                    fnametxtbox.Visible = True
                    fnametxtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    fnametxtbox.TabStop = True
                    fnametxtbox.TabIndex = 1
                    fnametxtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    fnametxtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    mnametxtbox.Enabled = False
                    mnametxtbox.Visible = True
                    mnametxtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    mnametxtbox.TabStop = True
                    mnametxtbox.TabIndex = 2
                    mnametxtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    mnametxtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    lnametxtbox.Enabled = False
                    lnamelabel.Visible = True
                    lnametxtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    lnametxtbox.TabStop = True
                    lnametxtbox.TabIndex = 3
                    lnametxtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    lnametxtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    addresstxtbox.Enabled = False
                    addresstxtbox.Visible = True
                    addresstxtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    addresstxtbox.TabStop = True
                    addresstxtbox.TabIndex = 4
                    addresstxtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    addresstxtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    address2txtbox.Enabled = False
                    address2txtbox.Visible = True
                    address2txtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    address2txtbox.TabStop = True
                    address2txtbox.TabIndex = 5
                    address2txtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    address2txtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    citytxtbox.Enabled = False
                    citytxtbox.Visible = True
                    citytxtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    citytxtbox.TabStop = True
                    citytxtbox.TabIndex = 6
                    citytxtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    citytxtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    statetxtbox.Enabled = False
                    statetxtbox.Visible = True
                    statetxtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    statetxtbox.TabStop = True
                    statetxtbox.TabIndex = 7
                    statetxtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    statetxtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    ziptxtbox.Enabled = False
                    ziptxtbox.Visible = True
                    ziptxtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    ziptxtbox.TabStop = True
                    ziptxtbox.TabIndex = 8
                    ziptxtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    ziptxtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    countrytxtbox.Enabled = False
                    countrytxtbox.Visible = True
                    countrytxtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    countrytxtbox.TabStop = True
                    countrytxtbox.TabIndex = 9
                    countrytxtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    countrytxtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    celltxtbox.Enabled = False
                    celltxtbox.Visible = True
                    celltxtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    celltxtbox.TabStop = True
                    celltxtbox.TabIndex = 10
                    celltxtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    celltxtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    studentidtxtbox.Enabled = False
                    studentidtxtbox.Visible = True
                    studentidtxtbox.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
                    studentidtxtbox.TabStop = True
                    studentidtxtbox.TabIndex = 11
                    studentidtxtbox.BackColor = Color.White
                    studentidtxtbox.ForeColor = Color.Black

                    fnamelabel.Visible = True
                    mnamelabel.Visible = True
                    lnamelabel.Visible = True
                    addressstreetlabel.Visible = True
                    address2label.Visible = True
                    addresscitylabel.Visible = True
                    addressstatelabel.Visible = True
                    addressziplabel.Visible = True
                    addresscountrylabel.Visible = True
                    celllabel.Visible = True
                    studentidlabel.Visible = True
                End If

                For Each DataRow In dt.Rows
                    If stunumtxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("studentId").ToString Then
                        fnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("firstName").ToString
                        mnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("midleInitial").ToString
                        lnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("lastName").ToString
                        addresstxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressStreet").ToString
                        address2txtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressOption").ToString
                        citytxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressCity").ToString
                        statetxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressState").ToString
                        ziptxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressZip").ToString
                        countrytxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressCountry").ToString
                        celltxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("contactcellphone").ToString
                        studentidtxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("studentId").ToString
                        StudentNameTextBox.Text = lnametxtbox.Text + "," + " " + fnametxtbox.Text + " " + mnametxtbox.Text
                    Else
                        fnamelabel.Visible = False
                        mnamelabel.Visible = False
                        lnamelabel.Visible = False
                        addressstreetlabel.Visible = False
                        address2label.Visible = False
                        addresscitylabel.Visible = False
                        addressstatelabel.Visible = False
                        addressziplabel.Visible = False
                        addresscountrylabel.Visible = False
                        celllabel.Visible = False
                        studentidlabel.Visible = False
                    End If
                Next
            End Using
        Catch se As SqlException
            MsgBox(se.Message)
        Finally
        End Try
    End If

    stunumtxtbox.Clear()
    stunumtxtbox.Select()

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Some simplification of your work. If your datatable has no rows then you have no matches.

```
Dim count = da.Fill(dt)
If count = 0 then
  ' you have no matches
  ' do you logic for no matches here
Else
  ' fill data
 fnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("firstName").ToString
 mnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("midleInitial").ToString
 lnametxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("lastName").ToString
 addresstxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressStreet").ToString
 address2txtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressOption").ToString
 citytxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressCity").ToString
 statetxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressState").ToString
 ziptxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressZip").ToString
 countrytxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("addressCountry").ToString
 celltxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("contactcellphone").ToString
 studentidtxtbox.Text = dt.Rows(0)("studentId").ToString
End If
```

`Try/Catches` are for things that may explode, how will this explode? Simple concatenating should not need a `Try/Catch`. And we use `&` in VB for concatenating. The outer one will not catch all exceptions since you narrowed it's catch ability to `SqlException` only.

```
 Try
   StudentNameTextBox.Text = lnametxtbox.Text + "," + " " + fnametxtbox.Text + " " + mnametxtbox.Text
 Catch ex As Exception
   MsgBox(ex.Message)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your first sentence, "If your datatable has no rows then you have no matches." My database will always have rows as there will always be students in it. I'm searching for a specific row that has a specific value entered by the end user and if that row doesn't exist then let me know so I can throw a 'not found' error to the user. Does that make sense? I'm trying to explain the best I can.

Comment: If your querying the db for a student by id why would you have more than one record returned? Also look into `Parameterized Queries` to avoid `SQL injection`.

Comment: There will never be more then one record per student_id. that would be a huge problem lol Thanks for your feedback...i'm still comparing and digesting your recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is doing exactly what you are telling to do. You fill and zero rows are returned if it is not an ID in the database. This is not an exception therefore it continues down to the connnection close then clears and selects your search box. You need to check for zero rows returned and throw the exception to the catch or just throw up a text box from the if/else where you check for zero. There is not one way to do this....

-m

P.S. to '*user3288293*'

are you still interested in this, also check out the last answer on here, it works.

Comment: Thank you @Michael! - would you happen to have a preference of which way to do it? Or a recommendation on the best way you'd do it?

Comment: @user3288293  I haven't look at this since I posted, have you figured this out or would you like for me to look at it again.